# Перенаправление с IP на домен

Tags: nginx, hosts, hosting, virtual, ip

В apache есть параметр, который определяет, что если юзер переходит по IP или несуществующему адресу, то его перебрасывает на опред. домен.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>  ServerAlias *  DocumentRoot /hdd/backup/www/</VirtualHost>
```

А в NGINX как так сделать? А то я перехожу по IP, а меня кидает на главную страницу NGINX :(

Comment: Это исправил. Осталось, что бы автоматически перенаправлял на домен, а не открывал файлы домена

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, то вот решение вашей проблемы: [Nginx и хост по умолчанию](http://vexell.ru/2010/11/nginx-и-хост-по-умолчанию/)

Comment: Тогда появляется проблема: index.html и htm открывается нормально, а если по умолчанию будет стоять index.php, то он не открывает его, а предлагает сохранить!

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например так:

```
    location / {    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://your.domen.com$1 break;    }
```

При условии, что это будет первый локейшен в конфиге.

Comment: Не срабатывает

Comment: Конфиг в студию.

Comment: http://pastecode.ru/9bda/Ещё ужасно долго грузятся сайты... и картинки не прогружаются..